# Essentia MusicExtractor python: Warning from AudioLoader

Tags: python, audio, feature-extraction

I am working with the Essentia's `MusicExtractor` to extract a bunch of features for different time frames on a relatively large music collection.

Example: To extract all standard features (plus statistics) for the time frame `[3.0, 6.0]` and the audio file `example.mp3`, i do:

```py
kwargs["startTime"] = 1.5
kwargs["endTime"] = 3.0
features = MusicExtractor(**kwargs)("example.mp3")[0]
```

Depending on the audio file and probably on the time frame, i sometimes get the following warning:

> [ WARNING  ] AudioLoader: invalid frame, skipping it: Invalid data
>   found when processing input

The features are calculated anyway, so i am not sure if it really is a problem. But if it is a problem then what does it mean and why does it happen?